# Testing Connection Pool In MEAN Stack

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

In my MEAN application, I have created a global mongoose connection. Default pool size is 5 for the same connection.
 I have added a MAP reduce which generally takes 6 sec for execution.
If 6 users hit the same function, One user stucks.
It may be because of we dont have connections available in connection pool.

So my question is that, is there any way to check available connection in pool using node.js (or may be Mongo, Not sure)

Comment: If the 6th request comes in, does it get "unstuck" when one of the other requests is finished? If so, then yes, your connection pool is too small.

Comment: Yes. It gets unstucked when one request is finished

Comment: How can i check the available pool.. what maximum value should i Use for connection pooling

Comment: I haven't found a way of checking if the pool is empty or not, so I think you should do some calculations on the number of expected concurrent users on your system and adjust the pool size accordingly. Perhaps also consider caching the map/reduce results if they take such a long time (provided that's possible), or check if you can speed it up using indexes (if you haven't done so already).

Comment: Is there any drawback of using poolsize 1000??

Comment: Your MongoDB should allow that number of connections to be made (but I think by default it will allow something like 64K connections, so that should be okay). Also, I don't know how much memory a single connection requires.